# Question about Bayesian Probability

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have difficulty understanding what I should do for this problem, can you help me? Specifically, I don't understand what probabilities I should start with given that the questions says I can't assume 0.9 to 0.1 probabilities. Maybe I'm wrong.

[image]

Here's the calculator if you need
http://psych.fullerton.edu/mbirnbaum/bayes/BayesCalc.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should start with $p=.50$. It says as much in the attached picture, quoted below.

> He figures, instead, that there is about a 50/50 chance of being killed in a serious car accident whether or not one is wearing a seatbelt.